# Hollow Cylinder with Walls and Top

Tags: solidify-modifier

I would like to make a cylinder that has walls of a certain thickness.  The top of the cylinder should have a "lid" with the same thickness as the walls.  The bottom should be open.  Like an upside down cup.

I can make the cylinder using Add>Mesh>Cylinder.  Then setting Cap Fill Type to N-Gon.  This gives me a cylinder with a top and bottom.  Next I go in Edit Mode and delete the bottom face.

Using the Solidify Modifier allows me to make walls of a specified thickness.

[image]
[image]
My issue is that the top face has no thickness.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: it should have thickness, could you please share your file?

Comment: I tried to make a sample model that would demonstrate this.  You are right.  The top does have thickness.  For some reason, my current design does not have this feature.  I dont remember how I made this.  I can remake it.  Thanks anyway!